# Unable to lookup JNDI name [jdbc/EPAR]

Tags: intellij-idea, jndi

```
org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [jdbc/EPAR]
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2277)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2273)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1782)
    at gov.srpmicnsn.ea.tes.service.HibernateSessionFactory.<clinit>(HibernateSessionFactory.java:33)
    at gov.srpmicnsn.ea.tes.merit.MeritIncreaseConfig.init(MeritIncreaseConfig.java:67)
    at gov.srpmicnsn.ea.tes.merit.MeritIncreaseInitializerContextListener.contextInitialized(MeritIncreaseInitializerContextListener.java:24)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4685)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5146)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1728)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/EPAR] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:833)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:160)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:140)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:65)
    ... 64 more
```

I have tried various things. Seeting up web.xml and context.xml still facing the same problem.

I have added this to  server.xml in tomcat9/conf/server.xml

```
<Resource maxWait="10000" minIdle="5" maxIdle="20" maxActive="100" password="pass" username="user"
 url="..." driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource" auth="Container" global="jdbc/EPAR" name="jdbc/EPAR"/>
```

I have added this to context.xml in tomcat9/conf/context.xml

```
<ResourceLink type="javax.sql.DataSource" name="jdbc/EPAR" global="jdbc/EPAR"/>
```

I have Configured the JNDI DataSource in Tomcat by adding a declaration for my resource to your Context.

Comment: Does it help if you configure it in the local application context inside the project? `WEB_ROOT/META-INF/context.xml`

Comment: No! i tried adding <ResourceLink type="javax.sql.DataSource" auth="Container" global="jdbc/EPAR" name="jdbc/EPAR"/> to META-INF/context.xml but didnt worked.

Comment: Please [contact support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new) and attach the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you please specify if you need any more details?

Comment: Yes, please share the sample project to support and we'll try to help you.

Comment: Its confidential but if you want specific file or configuration i can tell you that.

Comment: You can always prepare a dummy sample project with the similar structure.

Answer (score 0):

In tomcat you should add `java:comp/env/` to your hibernate datasource.
So it would look like this `java:comp/env/jdbc/EPAR`.